# Android Studio Layout Design disappeared

Tags: android, layout

***!!Solved!!***

[Designed Layout not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnW59.png)

When I am designing my project design layout disappeared, also the component tree shows "Nothing to Show". But Code is Still there and it's already running through an emulator. I restarted my laptop, close and reopened the project. but the problem is the same. what can I do?

this is my code

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/txtTopic"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/txtMsg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputTopic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/txtDate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputMsg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/txtClass"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputTime" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/DarkOrange"
        android:text="@string/btnAdd"
        app:cornerRadius="@dimen/btnCorner"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputClass" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputTopic"
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_rounded_corner"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/inputTopic"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputMsg"
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_rounded_corner"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:hint="@string/inputMsg"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_rounded_corner"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/inputDate"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_rounded_corner"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/inputTime"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/inputClass"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_rounded_corner"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/txtTime"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputDate" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: Try clicking on red alert on top of the design section to see what happen.

Comment: Thank You. That's worked

Comment: In my case it was due to Missing Classes. The layout had custom views and I previously did a Clean. After I did a build and run, the missing classes error is gone and the layout preview works as expected.